How to run a Telegram bot polling asynchronously without blocking the main application (using python-telegram-bot version >= 20)?
I am trying to run a Telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot library (version >= 20) in asynchronous mode. The problem is that when I start the polling, the whole application blocks. I have tried using both threading and asyncio.create_task() to prevent the polling from blocking the main application, but I keep encountering various errors.
Error:
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running<br>
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

I have tried various solutions without success. Has anyone experienced this with the library and can suggest a definitive solution to run the polling asynchronously without blocking the main application?

Hi. Please have a look at https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#running-ptb-alongside-other-asyncio-frameworks

It would be helpful if you added your code to the question, without seeing your code the best anyone can do is guess what the problem is and try to answer what they think the problem may be.

The error you're encountering is related to how asynchronous event loops are managed in Python, especially with asyncio. When you use python-telegram-bot version >= 20 in asynchronous mode, it relies on asyncio for managing the bot’s polling and other I/O operations.
Solution with asyncio:
import asyncio
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text('Hello! I am your bot.')

async def run_bot():
    application = Application.builder().token('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN').build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    await application.run_polling()

async def main():
    bot_task = asyncio.create_task(run_bot())
    await bot_task  # Add other async tasks if needed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

